# Changing data structure in the columns of a table without for loop

Tags: r

I have a table named 'data'. It has n columns. Every column has the same structure. (i.e, a character vector with two values 'yes', 'no'). I would like to recode these columns where 'yes' labels will be 1 and 'no' labels will be 0. I currently do it with a for loop as below. Is there a faster way of doing this using lapply or any other function?

```
for (i in (1:n)){

 data[data[,i]=='no',i]=0
 data[data[,i]=='yes',i]=1

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a matrix, then the straightforward

```
ifelse(data=="yes", 1, 0)
```

looks appealing.  If there could be anything else in `data` that is not "yes" or "no", then something like

```
matrix(c(yes=1, no=0)[data], nrow(data))
```

will cause `NA` values to appear in such places.

Both these solutions exploit `R`'s tendency to apply operations to all components of arrays simultaneously.  The first one is in the spirit of the attempt outlined in the question.  The second one takes advantage of associative addressing of arrays: `c(yes=1, no=0)` creates an array to perform the conversion and `[data]` performs that conversion by means of the `[` (extract) function.

If `data` is something else--such as a data frame--it will be quick and easy to convert it to a matrix (`as.matrix`), apply these fast, simple solutions, and then convert it back (`as.data.frame`).

Answer (score 0):

apply() and gsub() are your friends.

```
# random data frame of yes and no
m <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("yes","no"), 100, replace = T), 10))

# gsub each value
m <- apply(m, 2, function(y) gsub("yes","1",y))
m <- apply(m, 2, function(y) gsub("no","0",y))

# and assuming you want them as numeric and not character
m <- apply(m, 2, as.numeric)
```